# AngularJS virtual infinite scrolling with dynamic row height

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-material, infinite-scroll

I want to implement **infinite scroll** using **virtual ng-repeat**.

> But there is one caveat - I have dynamic row height.

Imagine simple chat. Length (content / height) of messages may vary.
I wonder how it's implemented in most messengers and G+, for example. They all had the same issue.
In G+ the feed has blocks with different height. Do they use ***Virtual Repeat***?

`md-virtual-repeat` and `collection-repeat` don't work for me because they want constant height for all rows (messages)

Even if I use them, there some scroll positioning issues.
They take dimensions from first element if none is specified explicitly.

`ngInfiniteScroll` has nothing common with word `virtual`. It spawns enormous amount of watchers.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I've used ngInfiniteScroll before and didn't have any problems, and the data being attached at the bottom was of different height's, it just calculates if you are almost at the end of the visible content and just fetches more data, I don't understand why this wouldn't work for you. Look at this demo: https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_async.html

Comment: The concept should be the same as with static height. There are several repeated elements surrounded by padding elements, just more complicated due to padding height calculation (sum of heights of previously shown elements).

Comment: @mojarras ngInfiniteScroll doesn't destroy's the top invisible elements. Once you scroll down to 5000 elements, you'll have 5000+ watchers.